# How to Place Two Input Fields Side-by-Side

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to place two input fields side-by-side for sometime now and and I can't get them to actually get inline. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group name1 col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="formText">FIRST NAME:*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="muverName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group name2 col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="formText">LAST NAME:*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="muverPhone">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to utilize Bootstrap as well, but I can't for the life of me get them to align side-by-side. Here's the corresponding CSS:

```
.name1 {
    float: left;
}   

.name2 {
    float: right;
}

#name {
    width: 223.67px;
    height: 40.25px;
}

.form-group {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.containerr {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is my output:

[image]

Whats the best way to place them side-by-side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bootstrap should do this for you. Looks like you're missing the `<div class="row">` around your columns:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group name1 col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="formText">FIRST NAME:*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="muverName">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group name2 col-md-6">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1## Heading ##" class="formText">LAST NAME:*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="muverPhone">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the size of your output, you might need to use different column sizes. Try to set `col-sm-6` or `col-xs-6` classes. `col-md-6` might be to large in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#name {
    width: 223.67px;
    height: 40.25px;
}

.form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 1px);
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5% !important;
    margin-right: 5% !important;
}

.form-control {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group name1 col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="formText">FIRST NAME:*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="muverName">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group name2 col-md-6">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="formText">LAST NAME:*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="muverPhone">
    </div>
</div>
```

The above should work on larger resolutions.