# How to get two input fields next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want to recreate 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgBiF.jpg), where you get a basic form but the input for first and last name need to be on the same line. I've been trying floats without success and I'm also getting issues with the labels(the need to be on top). Is it also okay to put divs in a form? I think I might have issues due to inputs being 100% of width but I dont see any other way of doing this.

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}
.lefthalf {
    grid-column: 1;
}
.righthalf {
    grid-column: 2;
    margin: 40px;
}

#submit {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 15%;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 75px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: rgb(74, 76, 83);
}




.form input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px;
    display: table-cell
}

.form input, label {
    display: block;
}

.firstandlast input, {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">  
        <div class="lefthalf">
            <img src="assets/books.jpg" style="max-width: 700px">
        </div>
        <div class="righthalf">
            <h1>It's going down for real.</h1>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.Excepturi eveniet magni ab eos consectetur sunt, eius consequatur vitae dignissimos reiciedis repellat, cupiditate qui necessitatibus voluptatibus minus dolorum modi te? Nihil!</p>
            <h2>About You</h2>
            <!--form goes here-->
                <form class="form">
                    <div class="firstandlast">
                        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" size="30" placeholder="Jane">
                        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" value="Doe">
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>                    <label for="typeofbookchoice">Type of book choice</label>
                    <input type="text" name="typeofbookchoice" value="hardcover">
                    <label for="phonenumber">Phone number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="555-555-5555">
                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit">

                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Place Two Input Fields Side-by-Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792857/how-to-place-two-input-fields-side-by-side)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach you could use here would be to leverage `display: flex` to get those items next to one another. Here's an example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.form {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}

form div {
  width: 45%;
}

.form input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.firstandlast {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="firstandlast">
    <div>
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstname" size="30" placeholder="Jane">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastname" value="Doe">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @AlpacaLuis No problem.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

(Note that I shortened the code a little to just include the inputs for first and last names.)

```css
#submit {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 15%;
}

.form input {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px;
  display: table-cell
}

.firstandlast input,
label {
  width: 200px;
}

.floating-input {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="firstandlast">
    <div class="floating-input">
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <br><input type="text" id="firstname" size="30" placeholder="Jane">
    </div>
    <div class="floating-input">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <br><input type="text" id="lastname" value="Doe">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: flex`

Here is a code pen using flex  https://codepen.io/avck25/pen/JjjqgBW